# Create custom template for blog

Tags: 7, nodes

How do I go about overriding the default template for content of the blog page (the index page that shows the blog teasers)?

Also I would like the original template code for this content so that I can rewrite my content effectively, is the .tpl.php somewhere within drupal core, that I could copy out into my theme?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is separate file for Blog content type. Because for Blog default **node.tpl.php** is called. If you want to create tpl file for blog, straight away copy file from node.tpl.php and create a tpl like **node--blog.tpl.php**.

And if you want to create **page tpl** for blog content type then you can create

**page--blog.tpl.php**

And you have to add some PHP code in template.php file in THEMENAME_preprocess_page() function

```
if( !empty($vars['node'])){
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'. $vars['node']->type;
  }
```

Comment: To target the index blog page you have to create page tpl for that. Just see the path and create a page template file according to path. Because in Drupal we can also create tpl according to path.

Comment: node--blog.tpl.php works great. page--blog.tpl.php works great for the individual blog entries but it doesn't seem to target the index blog page that shows all the summaries. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: So how do I target in that way? What should the filename of my template be called if URL is /blog?

Comment: If there is user/login then we can create tpl file like page--user--login.tpl.php. You can apply same concept in blog listing page also.

Answer (score 1):

I think, we don't need any php code in template.php file for create blog template file.
The files only enough for it ( I mean node--blog.tpl.php and page--blog.tpl.php )
After created the file clear your cache, then your new template will be worked.

Answer (score 0):

The best and fast option is use views, and in the views page url add the blog paths.

With [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) + [semantic views](http://drupal.org/project/semanticviews) + [display suit](http://drupal.org/project/ds) you can rebuild the html of your site without change no one *.tpl.php

Oskar

Answer (score 0):

Creating a node--blog.tpl.php and adding the following to the code worked for me.

```
<h2>
  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <?php print render($title); ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
</h2>
```

I didn't need to add the preprocess function.