# Hide user's blog link on blog entries

Tags: 7, nodes

I want to hide the *user's blog* link that appears on blog entries e.g *Anonymous's blog*

How can I do this in *node--blog.tpl.php*?

I tried `hide($content['author']);` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You could always just use display:none in a CSS and that way you don't have to mess with the php.

Comment: That would be:

`.blog_usernames_blog {`
 `display: none !important;`
`}`
For anyone who likes a dirty CSS hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code in your template.php file.

```
<?php
function phptemplate_links($links, $attributes = array()) {
    unset($links['blog_usernames_blog']);
    return theme_links($links, $attributes);
}
?>
```

To get the more information about all the links use following code:

```
<?php
function phptemplate_links($links, $attributes = array()) {
    print_r($links);
    return "Hello World";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your node--blog.tpl.php add `unset ($content['links']['blog']['#links']);` instead of `hide($content['author']);`

Answer (score 1):

For remove user blog link you have to just comment or remove bellow line from your  node--blog.tpl.php

`<?php print render($content['links']); ?>`

remove above line from your tpl file its remove user blog link perfectly

Comment: This would remove any link, not just the one the OP wants to remove.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the link you can try this. Taken from [here](https://www.drupalcasts.com/blog/remove-users-blog-link-view-recent-blog-entries):

```
function your_module_user_view_alter(&$build, $account, $display) {
  unset($build['summary']['blog']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a node tpl file for your blog content (reference: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/42653/1254). 
Then inside that file, you can use the below code:

```
unset ($content['links']['blog']['#links']); // Unset the blog links
print render($content['links']); // Print the links
```