# Getting rid of personal blogs

Tags: 7, nodes

I am using the built in blog module with Drupal 7, and I don't like the fact that "Every user gets a personal blog."

For instance, if a user with administrative privileges (Joe Schmoe from our company) makes a blog entry, within the blog entry, you will see a link for "view Joe Schmoe's blog." I would much rather it say "view (company name here)'s blog" or show nothing at all.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any settings for this. Is it possible to disable this feature or get this feature to work the way I would like?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/43840/hide-users-blog-link-on-blog-entries

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the title of the link using [hook_node_view_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7) in a custom module.

For example

```
function MY_MODULE_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  // dpm($build['links']['node']['#links']);
  $build['links']['node']['#links']['personal_blog']['title'] = t('view company blog');
}
```

You will have to use some logic to only apply the link to a certain user etc.

I'm not sure about the actual link concerned so if you have [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) installed, uncomment the dpm() part and inspect the array to find the correct link.

Comment: Well, I'm very new to Drupal, and I'm really stuck on trying to find `blog.module` which I can't seem to find anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, you don't want to edit the module anyway, you need to create your own module. Bit of learning curve but thats Drupal for you.