# How to edit breadcrumb in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

How to edit breadcrumb info without install any drupal module? 
Example: blog
Home >> blog >> admin's blog

I want to remove admin's blog

I cant find node--blog.tpl.php file.

I only can find node.tpl.php file.

[image]

Many Thank.

Comment: can you explain more detailed? on what info did you mean?

Comment: @mixerowsky, I had edited my question. Kindly take a look. Many thank.

Comment: @Topsitemakers Many Thanks. Do you have any idea where to find this file: node--blog.tpl.php add

Comment: No need to search for that file; check out [this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/43841/10041) specifically. Code from that answer should be pasted in your theme's `template.php` file.

Comment: @Topsitemakers I found template.php at sites/all/themes/responsive_bartik. I add this code: function responsive_bartik_links($links, $attributes = array()) {
    unset($links['blog_usernames_blog']);
    return theme_links($links, $attributes);
}
Not working.

Comment: If you need node--blog.tpl.php you simply have to create it by duplicating your node.tpl.php file and then rename it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in page.tpl.php replace with breadcrumb code.

```
$breadcrumb_array = drupal_get_breadcrumb();
```

print $breadcrumb_array[0]

drupal_get_breadcrumb() gives the array.

You can use array as you want.

Please let me know code worked for you

Comment: Not really a good solution. 
Example: 
Home >> book >> may<br>
Home >> blog >> admin' blog<br>
Home >> car >> color >> brand<br>

Dun really work for my case. I only wan to remove admin's blog

Comment: You can use if condition if($breadcrumb_array[$i] != " admin' blog" )
{
print $breadcrumb_array[$i];
}

Answer (score 1):

Check the [menu_get_active_trail()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_active_trail/7) and [menu_set_active_trail()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_set_active_trail/7) functions. They should be of use for what you want (retreiving and changing your breadcrumb).

Try the following in your template.php in your theme :

```php
/**
 * Implementing theme_preprocess_html
 */
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
    $crumbs = menu_get_active_trail();
    $count = count($crumbs);
    // dpm($crumbs);
    unset($crumbs[$count - 1]);
    menu_set_active_trail($crumbs);
}
```

See how it goes.

Comment: Sorry I dun get what you mean...

Answer (score 1):

you can override breadcrumbs theme in your template.php file

$variables : An array containing the breadcrumb links

```
/**
 * Implementing theme_breadcrumb
 */

function theme_breadcrumb($variables) {
  $breadcrumb = $variables ['breadcrumb'];

  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
    // edit $breadcrumbs here
    $output = '<div class="breadcrumb">' . implode(' » ', $breadcrumb) . '</div>';
    return $output;
  }
}
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_breadcrumb/7